# error message 'module' object has no attribute 'MarkerCluster'

Tags: python, leaflet, markers, folium

I'm trying to create a very simple leaflet/folium map using python. 
It works without marker clusters (all the relevant locations show up on the map), but when I try using MarkerCluster I get the following error message `'module' object has no attribute 'MarkerCluster'` (in response to line 14, marker_cluster = folium.MarkerCluster().add_to(cyclemap)).
  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've imported the package, I've definitely installed folium correctly. 
My text editor also states `'folium.plugins.MarkerCluster imported but unused'`.

I'm completely new to python.

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
import pandas as pd
cyclemap = folium.Map(location = [51.5074, -0.1278],
                  tiles='CartoDB positron',
                  zoom_start = 11, 
                  width = 800, height = 600)

cycleincidences = pd.read_csv("2016cyclists.csv")

MAX_RECORDS = 50 
#using max records for speed as I have almost 5000 data points 

marker_cluster = folium.MarkerCluster().add_to(cyclemap)

for each in cycleincidences[0:MAX_RECORDS].iterrows():
 folium.Marker(
    location = [each[1]['X'],each[1]['Y']]
    ).add_to(marker_cluster)

cyclemap.save('cylesmap3.html')
```

Answer (score 3):

According to this notebook (https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/MarkerCluster.ipynb) you should try calling MarkerCluster directly. This is because you have imported that module already.

```
marker_cluster = MarkerCluster().add_to(cyclemap)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to expand a bit on @dslamb's answer, look at the imports in your code.

You use:

```
from folium.plugins import MarkerCluster
```

And then in your code you do:

```
marker_cluster = folium.MarkerCluster().add_to(cyclemap)
```

which , as your error notes, "doesn't exist".

You need to either use MarkerCluster the same way you imported it, so from the `plugins` sub-object, like this `folium.plugins.MarkerCluster()` or directly (since you've imported it as a stand alone too) like `MarkerCluster()`.